# Fancybox Content do not refresh

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox

I have a problem with my Fancybox, I'm trying to retrieve some php data, but is not reloading properly, I used firebug to track the activity on my page, and it seems that is in fact retrieving the right data from my DB but Fancybox doesn't parse that info, it just shows the first value. Here's my fancybox

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".various").fancybox({
    fitToView   : false,
    width       : '70%',
    height      : '70%',
    autoSize    : true,
    closeClick  : false,
    scrolling   : 'auto',
    titlePosition     : 'inside',
    openEffect  : 'fade',
    closeEffect : 'fade',
    type : 'inline'
}



});
});
```

And here's a piece of my php code, I'm having problems retrieving the $value['managementSummary']:

```
echo '<td><p class="various" href="#inline" title="Reference ID # ' . $referenceId . '">' .$value['managementSummary']. ' ...(+)';  
echo '<div style="display: none;"><div id="inline" style="width:400px;height:200px;overflow:auto;"> '. $value['managementSummary'] .'  </p></td></div>';
```

I know that i have to refresh my content with some sort of function like:

```
beforeLoad : function() {
this.content = '. $value['managementSummary'] .';
```

And of course it doesnt work, any ideas??? Thanks!!!

Comment: why not `afterLoad` instead of `beforeLoad`?

Comment: Maybe I can use that, but i dont know if my function is well created. This is my first time using fancybox and jquery!... can you explain a little bit more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to fix this issue, i used this code in my fancybox call:

```
afterLoad: function(){
                this.content = $(this.element).attr('rel');
            }
```

And I changed my php code as well:

```
echo '<td><p>' .truncate($value['managementSummary']). ' <a href="#inline" class="various" rel="'. $value['managementSummary'] .'" title="Reference ID # ' . $referenceId . '">...(+)</a></p></td>';
echo '<div id="inline" style="width:400px;height:200px;display:none;"> '. $value['managementSummary'] .'  </div></td>';
```

It was weird that my content wasn't displaying in the right way, so I used a different div attribute "Rel" to parse my solution.